# Static method is not a function: Typescript. Vue

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have defined static method as following.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class GraphService {

    public static post(query: string, variables: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            axios
                .post('https://localhost:44375/api/Graph', {
                    query,
                    variables,
                }).then((response) => {
                    return resolve(response.data.data);
                });
        });
    }

}
```

I am calling it from my vue component as following.

```
GraphService.post(`{   project {
                                    id,
                                    name,
                                    datasource {
                                        id,
                                        name,
                                        type
                                    }
                                  }
                                }`, null)
```

But I am getting following error.

```
TypeError: _services_GraphService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16___default.a.post is not a function
```

and vue component gives warning as below:

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: _services_GraphService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16___default.a.post is not a function"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you importing GraphService in your vue component?

Comment: Import GraphService from '../service/graphservice';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no issue in the code, but thewe was a .js and map.js files generated. I deleted that and this code started working. Strange.

Comment: If in VS Code, are you having it compile the maps every time you build? If not, this can be frustrating to troubleshoot

Comment: Check the vscode marketplace for typescript auto compiler